# MySQL Update Error Incorrect datetime Value

Tags: mysql, datetime

Our database uses '0000-00-00 00:00:00' as the default value for many datetime and timestamp fields. MySQL has apparently decided that they only want us to use a valid date or null for these types of fields.

However, the '0000-00-00 00:00:00' values used to be acceptable and our code checks for this value. When I setup a new server, I edit the /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf file and add one line to the [mysqld] section.

```
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Today I have attempted to setup a new server. I added the `sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` to the MySQL configuration and restarted the mysql service. However, this new server only gets errors.

```
UPDATE example_table SET active = 1 WHERE example_table_id = 1;
ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'my_date_field' at row 1
```

I could of course update the database to have NULL values or a "valid" default date such as '1970-01-01 00:00:01', but this **would break existing code** that checks the data for '0000-00-00 00:00:00'.

Additional Example Information:

```
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 - (Ubuntu)
Protocol version: 10
innodb_version: 5.7.22

SELECT my_date_field FROM example_table WHERE active = 1;
+---------------------+
| my_date_field       |
+---------------------+
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+


DESC example_table;
+------------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+
| Field                              | Type         | Null | Key | Default             |
+------------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+
| my_date_field                      | datetime     | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
| active                             | tinyint(2)   | NO   |     | 1                   |
+------------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+
```

I've got other machines on the same version of MySQL working with just `sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` and I'm almost to the point of just imaging one of those for this new machine, until such time as the code is updated to look for a valid date or null instead of '0000-00-00 00:00:00'.

Comment: I had a similar issue when revived an old project (no error for insert, error for update when updating other field, like in your case) and it turned out I had a trigger which compared the column to '' (empty string). When I changed so it compared against '0000-00-00 00:00:00', it worked. (This is w/o NO_ZERO_DATE in sql_mode).

Answer (score 0):

The [`NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` SQL mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_engine_substitution) doesn't have anything to do with dates. It only did the trick for you because by setting it you also removed the server's default mode, which in modern versions is something on the line of [`TRADITIONAL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_traditional), which is a combination mode that, among others, includes [`NO_ZERO_IN_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_in_date) and [`NO_ZERO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date).

You possibly just want to set a legacy mode for this application at session level, e.g.:

```
SET @@SESSION.sql_mode = '';
```